# Azure SQL server storage - Page or Block Blob

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

What sort of Storage will you use for Azure SQL server PaaS (without VM), will it be Page Blob or Block Blob and why?

The complete solution is on azure and nothing is on premise.

Comment: The differences are well-documented, as are the uses for both. Look at the answer I posted on the question I linked to.

Comment: That said: I don't know what you're referring to, regarding storage for SQL Server PaaS. If you're referring to SQL Database service, you don't allocate any blobs - the storage is part of the service.

Comment: That exactly what i wanted to know if the service includes the storage too. Do I get a choice of selecting page or block blob as a configuration option?

Comment: I think you're missing the point. SQL Service storage is part of the service. How it's implemented is irrelevant. And you're making an assumption that blobs are even used within the service (and perhaps they are; my point is that it's opaque).

Comment: Yeah, I completely understand that they are opaque and we would not have any control or would want to have the overhead of managing the storage as Azure takes care of it.

We are actually migrating an existing website and I found that the website can be exported as a blob through SQl server client to Azure and then it can be imported within Azure SQL server.

After import can we delete the storage account and the associated blob as the data now resides in Azure SQL PaaS.